# CSS - fluid divs in between fixed width & centered positioned divs

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout, fixed-width

Well. I am having a torrid time with this one!

In fact I can't get it going at all.

I am looking for a full page width, with two divs taking up 50% each, one on the left side and one on the right side.

Over the top of those two divs I want a series of divs, one div (div5) in the middle of the page.

Either side of the middle div I want a fixed witdh div that shows in horitzonal center of each side of the page. So div3 is center of div1 and div7 is center of div2.

Then in between those fixed width divs I want two fluid divs to fill the space between the middle div and the fixed width divs on either side.

Some CSS God please save me from this nightmare! :D

No need for IE6, 7 support. 8 preferable but can skip if it is a hassle.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: is vertical distance from top of page for the div 3-7 defined or percent?

Answer (score 1):

**Finally...** made it to work on Firefox 21 from local file. For some reason, it,s not working in Internet Explorer 8. The good news is that NO jQuery is required. I am posting the whole code, along with the layout of the html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px;}
div {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px;}

#div1 {background-color: #999; min-height: 350px; width: 50%; float: left;}
#div2 {background-color: #222; min-height: 350px; width: 50%; float: left;}
#div8 {position: absolute; top: 100px;} 
#div3 {background-color: #333; min-height: 100px; width: 150px; float: left;}  
#div4 {background-color: #444; min-height: 100px; min-width: 10px; float: left;}
#div5 {background-color: #555; min-height: 100px; width: 80px; float: left;}
#div6 {background-color: #666; min-height: 100px; min-width: 10px; float: left;}
#div7 {background-color: #777; min-height: 100px; width: 150px; float: left;}

</style>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

function center()
{
var ww = window.innerWidth;
var div8w = document.getElementById('div8').offsetWidth;
var div3w = document.getElementById('div3').offsetWidth;
var div5w = document.getElementById('div5').offsetWidth;
var div7w = document.getElementById('div7').offsetWidth;    
document.getElementById('div4').style.width = ((ww - div3w - div5w - div7w)/4)+"px";
document.getElementById('div6').style.width = ((ww - div3w - div5w - div7w)/4)+"px";    
var div4w = document.getElementById('div4').offsetWidth;
var div6w = document.getElementById('div6').offsetWidth;
divLeft = ((ww - div3w - div5w - div7w - div4w - div6w)/2);
document.getElementById('div8').style.marginLeft = divLeft+'px';
setTimeout(center, 500);
}

function rS()
{
if ((document.readyState == 'interactive') || (document.readyState == 'complete'))
  {
   center();
  }
  setTimeout(rS, 100);
}

document.onload = rS();

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div8">
    <div id="div3">div3</div>
    <div id="div4">div4</div>
    <div id="div5">div5</div>
    <div id="div6">div6</div>
    <div id="div7">div7</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the desired look, but not the desired operation. You have divs 4 and 6 as fixed percentages. Divs 3, 5 and 7 need to be fixed width (px) and divs 4 and 6 fluid and fill the space between the fixed width divs.